# Is it possible to show the methods of class in xtext as java in eclipse

Tags: xtext

In xtext, I need to know randomly generated word
and if dot is followed by it. I know how to check it in the available list I had and show all the classes when I pressed ctrl+Space bar. Is this possible in xtext?

Comment: Could you be more explicit (e.g. Example)

Comment: Thanks Christian Dietrich for the response. Actually i am having the list of classes and methods in the buffer which are obtained through java code. So now i am using xtext for building IDE.so my requirement when i type the class name followed by dot,it should show the corresponding methods in xtext while pressing ctrl + Space bar.Is it possible in xtext?

Comment: Did you have a look at YourDslProposalProvider